# can't delete twice from a dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

First time when i delete from data set all good
but second time it gave me this error
Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["emp"].Rows)
        {
            if (row[0].ToString() == textBox6.Text)
            {
                row.Delete();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not modify a collection while you're iterating it.

Comment: actually when i start deleting rows from below there is no error
but what if i want to delete unsorted rows

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: how can i delete a 2nd row after deleting the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally deleting from a collection while enumerating will throw an exception:

`Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.`

In this case, if the data rows haven't just been added, calling `DataRow.Delete()` doesn't remove the row;  it sets the `RowState` to `Deleted`, but the row remains in the collection until you call `AcceptChanges` (see the documentation for [`DataRow.Delete()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So the row is still in the `DataTable` and the second time you enumerate the collection, the code tries to access the field value and you get the exception:

`DeletedRowInaccessibleException: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.`

To avoid this error, you can either call `AcceptChanges` to commit the deletion or check the `RowState` as mentioned in the answer linked to by @Grant Winney.

To see an example of this, you can run this code:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("foo");
table.Rows.Add("bar");

table.AcceptChanges();

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    if ((string)row["Name"] == "foo")
    {
        row.Delete();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[0].RowState);  // Deleted
Console.WriteLine(table.Rows.Count);        // 2
table.Rows[0].AcceptChanges();
Console.WriteLine(table.Rows.Count);        // 1
```